# Spring @Value : with Dynamic arraylist

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

My scenario' is reading a dynamic list of values from database and passing this ArrayList to @Value.

I defined like below,

```
@Value("#{getListOExpressions.split(',')}")
private List<String> secondSchedule;
```

and `getListOExpressions` is bean which returns `arrayList`. When I run I am getting error saying evaluating expression not of type `java.lang.string` with comma separated.

How to pass `arraylist` to`@value` ? .And I am not reading from properties file.

My exact camel code is

```
@Value("#{getListOfExpressions}")
private List<String> secondSchedule;

@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {


    from("quartz2://fraudIngestion/ruleExecuteSecondSequence?cron=" + secondSchedule + "")
    .log("Start executing secondSequence Rule")
            .bean(RulesExecutor.class, "getExecuteRuleWithSecondSequence(" + secondSchedule + ")")
            .log("Completed executing secondSequence Rule").end();



            }
```

Comment: why don't you do this in a method, and `getListOExpressions` this should be method right?

Comment: Can you post exact error?

Comment: Try this @Value("#{'#{getListOelExpressions}'.split(',')}")

Answer (score 0):

`getListOExpressions()` should return a String of comma separated items, not any Array List

Comment: is there anyway i can read ArrayList against @value??or do I have return one string to one @value and second string second @value??

Comment: what does that returns `getListOExpressions()` @Sri

Comment: Have you tried @Value("#{beanName. listOExpressions}") private List secondSchedule; ?

Comment: what is the beanName here?

Comment: getListOExpressions returns ArrayList<String> @Deapool

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E: Method call: Method split(java.lang.String) cannot be found on type java.util.ArrayList  This is the error I am getting.

Comment: If I just use below like this 
    @Value("#{getListOfCronExpressions}")
    private List<String> secondSchedule;  I am getting list ,but not sure how can pass it to camel route cronScheduler.

Comment: what is the class and bean containing `getListOfCronExpressions`? Bean is the bean name of that instance

Answer (score 0):

The example below works fine:

```java
package com.stackoverflow.q54121739;

import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import org.junit.ClassRule;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.convert.support.DefaultConversionService;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.rules.SpringClassRule;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.rules.SpringMethodRule;

@SuppressWarnings("javadoc")
public class Answer {

    /** The Constant SPRING_CLASS_RULE. */
    @ClassRule
    public static final SpringClassRule SPRING_CLASS_RULE = new SpringClassRule();

    /** The spring method rule. */
    @Rule
    public final SpringMethodRule springMethodRule = new SpringMethodRule();

    static final List<String> EXPECTED = Stream.of("first", "second")
        .collect(toList());

    @Value("#{listOfExpressions}")
    List<String> secondSchedule;

    @Value("#{listOfExpressionsAsCommaDelimitedString}")
    List<String> secondScheduleFromCommaDelimitedString;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println(this.secondSchedule);
        System.out.println(this.secondScheduleFromCommaDelimitedString);
        assertEquals(2, this.secondSchedule.size());
        assertEquals(2, this.secondScheduleFromCommaDelimitedString.size());
        assertEquals(EXPECTED, this.secondSchedule);
        assertEquals(EXPECTED, this.secondScheduleFromCommaDelimitedString);

    }

    @Configuration
    static class Config {

        Config(ConfigurableApplicationContext configurableApplicationContext,
                DefaultConversionService conversionService) {
            super();
            configurableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory()
                .setConversionService(conversionService);
        }

        @Bean
        public static DefaultConversionService conversionService() {
            return new DefaultConversionService();
        }

        @Bean
        List<String> listOfExpressions() {
            return EXPECTED;
        }

        @Bean
        String listOfExpressionsAsCommaDelimitedString() {
            return EXPECTED.stream()
                .collect(joining(","));
        }
    }
}
```

Dependencies in example:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I can see the list coming to value if use above but ,I have to iterate over list and pass that cron expression to camel quartz scheduler ,that is where i am facing the challenge problem.

Comment: I think you need a more detailed example.  Where do you have to iterate over the list?

Comment: in  cron scheduler,I edited my actual question with my exact code

Comment: can you show how `getListOExpressions` is being created?

Comment: Use @Resource to inject Collection beans